# Why the moving average in the reactive state engine is empty using a DolphinDB udf?

Tags: dolphindb

I defined the function `get_ma3` in my code. However, when calling sma(c, 3), the output is empty. I am not sure why that is the case...

```
def get_posneg(o, c){return iif(c > o, "pos", iif(c < o, "neg", "doji"))}
def get_ma3(c){return (sma(c, 3))}
ohlc_rse = createReactiveStateEngine(name = "ohlc_rse", metrics=[<datetime>, <get_posneg(o, c)>, <get_ma3(c)>], dummyTable=ohlc, outputTable=res_ohlc, keyColumn="symbol") subscribeTable(tableName = `ohlc, actionName="ohlc_action", handler = tableInsert{ohlc_rse})
```

Answer (score 1):

You need to add @state before your defined function in DolphinDB. User-defined state functions are available in the reactive state engine. Note these points:

- before defining the function, add @state to indicate the function is a udf
- only assignment and return statements can be used in a udf, and the return statement must be the last statement and can return multiple values
- use the `iif` function to express `if...else` logic